# this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to use Lambda in my class. My code builds but when i come to the page this is the error I am receiving. As another question had suggested i added parameters to my main query. I am still receiving this error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Adds.Areas.Mvc.Models.tblUserMenuMapping]
>   FindByExp(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Adds.Areas.Mvc.Models.tblUserMenuMapping,System.Boolean]])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
public List<tblMenu> GetChildMenusClass()
{
    var UserInfo = GetUserInfo();
    UserType = UserInfo[0].UserTypeID;          
    List<tblUserMenuMapping> MenuMapping = GetMenuIdFromUserMenuMappings();

    List<string> MenuMappingMenuId= new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MenuMapping.Count; i++)
    { 
        MenuMappingMenuId.Add(MenuMapping[i].MenuID.ToString());
    }

    List<tblRoleMenuMapping> RoleMapping = GetMenuIdFromRoleMenuMappings();
    List<string> RoleMenuId = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < RoleMapping.Count; i++)
    {
        RoleMenuId.Add(RoleMapping[i].MenuID.ToString());
    }

    var menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(Menus => ((Menus.IsDeleted == false) &&
         (DataAccess.UserMenuMappings.FindByExp(UserMenuMapping => (UserMenuMapping.UserID == Global.CurrentProfile.UserID))
         .Select(UserMenuMapping => new { MenuID = UserMenuMapping.MenuID }).Contains(new { MenuID = Menus.MenuID }) ||
          DataAccess.RoleMenuMappings.FindByExp(RoleMenuMapping => DataAccess.UserRoleMappings.FindByExp(UserRoleMapping => (UserRoleMapping.UserID == Global.CurrentProfile.UserID))
         .Select(UserRoleMapping => new { RoleID = UserRoleMapping.RoleID }).Contains(new { RoleID = RoleMenuMapping.RoleID }))
         .Select(RoleMenuMapping => new { MenuID = RoleMenuMapping.MenuID }).Contains(new { MenuID = Menus.MenuID }))))
         .Select(Menus => new tblMenu { MenuID = Menus.MenuID, MenuName = Menus.MenuName }).ToList();

    return menus;
}
```

First I converted my query to linq in linqer then converted to Lambda in LINQPad4. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I had looked at that answer and tried to add info to my main query. Also, they are using Iqueryable interface where i am using List.

Comment: Slow, but try changing `var menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp` to `var menus = DataAccess.Menus.AsEnumerable().FindByExp`.  The problem is that `FindByExp` is not LINQ, and it doesn't know how to convert to it SQL.  By putting `.AsEnumerable` in there, it will force LINQ to pull the entire table from the database, and then use LINQ to Objects for your `FindByExp` method.